# c# npoi lib: how to generate word doc with 2 tables in the same row

Tags: c#, cpu-word, npoi

I am using https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi

Does anyone know how I can create word document with 2 tables in the same row?
By default second table is created below the first table but I would like to have table1 next in the same row some spaces/tabs and next in the same row table2.

I am trying this code but it adds second table below the first table.

```
               XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

                XWPFTable table = doc.CreateTable(1, 1);

                table.GetRow(0).GetCell(0).SetText("TABLE1");

                XWPFTable table1 = doc.CreateTable(1, 1);

                table1.GetRow(0).GetCell(0).SetText("TABLE2");
```

-Jacek

Answer (score 1):

A new NPOI example is added at https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi-examples/tree/main/xwpf/ComplexTableLayout to show show how to do this.